# Node CSV pull parser

Tags: node.js, csv, parsing

I need to parse a CSV document from Node.JS, performing database operations for each record (= each line). However, I'm having trouble finding a suitable CSV parser using a pull approach, or at least a push approach that waits for my record operations before parsing the next row.

I've looked at `csv-parse`, `csvtojson`, `csv-streamify`, but they all seem to push events in a continuous stream without any flow control. If parsing a 1000 line CSV document, I basically get all 1000 callbacks in quick sequence. For each record, I perform an operation returning a promise. Currently I've had to resort to pushing all my promises into an array and after getting the `done/end` event I also wait for `Promise.all(myOperations)` to know when the document has been fully processed. But this is not very nice, and also, I'd prefer parsing one line at a time and fully processing it, before getting the next record, instead of concurrently processing all records - it's hard to debug and uses a lot of memory as opposed to simply dealing with each record sequentially.

So, is there a CSV parser that supports pull mode, or a way to get any stream-based CSV parser (preferably `csvtojson` as that's the one I'm using at the moment) to only produce events for new records when my handler for the previous record is finished (using promises)?

Comment: Take a look at `scramjet` and the `StreangStream.CSVParse` method. You'll need to set the maxParallel option there to make sure you're running just one operation side by side but it'll get your job done.

Oh - and it does use promises and/or async functions into account natively.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process each line asynchronously you can do that with node's native [LineReader](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html).

```
const lineStream = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('data/test.csv'),
});

lineStream.on('line', (eachLine) =>{
    //process each line
});
```

If you want to do the same in synchronous fashion you can use [line-by-line](https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-by-line). It doesn't buffer the entire file into memory. It provides event handlers to pause and resume the 'line' emit event.

```
lr.on('line', function (line) {
    // pause emitting of lines...
    lr.pause();

    // ...do your asynchronous line processing..
    setTimeout(function () {

        // ...and continue emitting lines. (1 sec delay)
        lr.resume();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Does this prevent further `line` events from being omitted until the code I want to run for the previous line is finished (promise is resolved)? Also, there is no CSV parser involved. I don't see how this is any different than using one of the CSV libraries I mentioned, getting events for each (parsed) line as json - the problem I'm having is that I don't want any more events until I'm finished handling the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself by creating my own `Writable` and piping the CSV parser to it. My write method does its stuff and wraps a promise to the node callback passed to _write() (here implemented using Q.nodeify):

```
class CsvConsumer extends stream.Writable {
    _write(data, encoding, cb) {
        console.log('Got data: ', data);

        Q.delay(1000).then(() => {
            console.log('Waited 1 s');
        }).nodeify(cb);
    }
}

csvtojson()
    .fromStream(is)
    .pipe(new CsvConsumer())
    .on('finish', err => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error!');
        } else {
            console.log('Done!');
        }
    });
```

This will process lines one by one:

```
Got data: {"a": "1"}
Waited 1 s
Got data: {"a": "2"}
Waited 1 s
Got data: {"a": "3"}
Waited 1 s
Done!
```